# Custom Shortcuts for Texmaker

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, latex

I'm using Texmaker 3.1 to write Latex documents and wonder how I can define my own shortcuts. For example I need a shortcut (<kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) for `\enquote{}`. Are custom shortcuts an unsupported scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Windows? An easy way to do it would be [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) where you can define a Hotkey for Texmaker which then sends the keys for `\enquote{}`.